# Need local SDK tool for parsing native pdf file with large tables

Tags: parsing, pdf, local

User needs to parse native-pdf(selectable data, not scanned, no OCR required) in local. The pdf files may be over 400 pages with large tables. Some tables may not have clear borders. Is there any API I could use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I know you don't want an API, I might recommend that you check out ItextSharp, from nuget. I have used this several times in the past, and there are many stack overflow forums on how to use it.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/5.5.13.1

EDIT: I apologize, it looks like iTextSharp has been replaced with iText 7 https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are several PDF parser APIs out there you could use. PDFTron looks promising, and they offer a free trial: https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-sdk/parsing-library/

DocParser may also be helpful for you, https://docparser.com/features.

I found all of these through a simple google search, so it may benefit you to do some research for yourself. As we can only make broad suggestions based on the information in your question.

Comment: Thanks, Ncarlson. The issue is the tools I found from google search are mostly cloud API that needs to upload files to their server to do the processing (like the two you suggested). My user needs the process engine to be in our local machine. Also, find some local API like ByteScout and tabula but the table processing is not that good. Still trying to find the best solution. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: You want to use an API to do something locally?

Comment: Actually, I should say local sdk that provides the ability to parse the pdf locally. Just modified the title. Thanks

Comment: Your question still states "API" you may want to re-ask this completely. I would look into ItextSharp from nuget.